# Twilio Connect -Create TWIML Application programmatically

Tags: php, web-services, twilio, phone-call, twilio-twiml

Currently I use Twilio normally in my app.
I have created and configured TWIML application manually in my Twilio account.

When migrating to Twilio Connect I will no longer have access to account.
All I will have is Account SID and Security Token.
I will be able to use this account, yes.
But I need to create TWIML Application there.

**Is there some way to crate TWIML Applications programmatically** (some API I think) or I need to ask people who will provide me their accounts SID and ST to create TWIML Apps manually **?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can post to the Applications resource to create a new application for an account:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications#list-post

Here are the docs for creating an Application using the PHP helper library:

https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/applications.html#creating-applications